# How can I create a relationship at runtime in Neomodel?

Tags: python, neo4j, neomodel

I am trying to create a relationship at runtime in Neomodel.  Let's say I have a Person model with no relationships:

```
class Person(StructuredNode):
    forename = StringProperty()
    surname = StringProperty()
```

At runtime there will be lots of relationships between people and these will be fed in dynamically.  I thought I could do something like the following to add a relationship dynamically at runtime.

```
for relationship in dynamic_relationships: #dynamic_relationships is a list
    r = RelationshipTo('Person', relationship) #error appears here
    person1.r.connect(person2)
```

However, the line marked gets a `ValueError: call stack is not deep enough`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Can I even declare a relationship at runtime in Neomodel?  Or will I have to use Cypher instead?